# AWS Cognito get new id_token

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I'm using implicit grant for one particular client (web-based admin portal) for an application that uses Cognito-integrated auth for other parts of the application (API Gateway, etc).

The problem is, the id token I get from Cognito Oauth expires after one hour, but I still need that token to send to API Gateway to signify that I have an authenticated user.

How do I get a new id token (remember, I'm using implicit grant, so I don't have a refresh token)?

Do I have to re-send the user's credentials to Cognito's auth endpoint every hour? That seems extravagantly un-secure for several reasons.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure why you are using the ID token even after it is expired. Ideally, a new token should be created after one hour. It should not be used after it is expired.

Comment: Yes. I know, I can't use the toke after it's expired, because it's expired. How is the new token "issued"? Am I meant to check for expiration and send the user's username and password again to get a new token?

Answer (score 0):

If you use implicit grant there is no way of refreshing the tokens (Storing credentials and using it to get new id tokens doesn't count here since its takes away the purpose of using OpenID Connect).

This is why the code grant is there. Unless you use code grant, refreshing the tokens are not possible.

You can use [AWS Amplify](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify) library to simplify the login where it takes cares of the refreshing and other heavy liftings if you use the code grant including using federated identities to access AWS resources such as S3.